# issues converting coordinate point to view point

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uikit

Basically I've been working with the coordinate points mostly, I also prefer using it because the bottom left is the origin. I found the following code that I want to use. It creates a rectangle at the top of the screen.

```
private let minimalHeight: CGFloat = 50.0
private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
// MARK: -
override func loadView() {
  super.loadView()

  shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.bounds.width, height: minimalHeight)
  shapeLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 57/255.0, green: 67/255.0, blue: 89/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
  view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

  view.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panGestureDidMove:"))
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: Methods

func panGestureDidMove(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  if gesture.state == .Ended || gesture.state == .Failed || gesture.state == .Cancelled {

  } else {
    shapeLayer.frame.size.height = minimalHeight + max(gesture.translationInView(view).y, 0)
  }
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .LightContent
}
```

I want to have the rectangle at the bottom of the screen so I can pan upwards rather so I changed `shapeLayer.frame` to

```
shapeLayer.frame = view.convert(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: minimalHeight), from: (view.window?.screen.coordinateSpace)!)
```

but this line gives an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` error when I run the code. How can I convert the rectangle stated in coordinate points for `shapeLayer.frame` above?

**UPDATE**

Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting, `shapeLayer.frame` is at the top of the screen though I want it to be at the bottom so I can pan upwards.

[image]

Comment: change `view.window?.screen.coordinateSpace)!` to `UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.screen.coordinateSpace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(view.window?.screen.coordinateSpace)!` is causing the issue.

change `(view.window?.screen.coordinateSpace)!` to `UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.screen.coordinateSpa‌​ce`

Comment: Thanks, that has solved the error, but I thought my coordinates should change the rectangle (`shapeLayer.frame`) from getting created at the top of the screen to the bottom? why is it still at the top, am I missing something?

Comment: can you add the screen shot

Comment: `shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: view.bounds.height-minimalHeight, width: view.bounds.width, height: minimalHeight)` will work.

Comment: The `shapeLayer.frame` is now at the button, but my    `shapeLayer.frame.size.height = minimalHeight + max(gesture.translationInView(view).y, 0)`
 in `panGestureDidMove(gesture:` doesn't seem to be working. It's not responding to panning

Comment: I guess I should be asking a different question for this